# Is it legal to create and use an OpenGL object without generating its name?

Tags: opengl

Typically an object such as a texture, framebuffer, shader, or vertex array, is set up by first generating a name, then binding it, then setting parameters:

```
GLuint texture_id;
glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ...);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ...);
```

It's noteworthy that `glGenTextures` does not actually create a texture object, only a name (ID number) for one, and marks it as used. Is it also legal to pick a number myself that is known to be unused, as in the following code?

```
// no other textures have been created so all numbers are available
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 42);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ...);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ...);
```

Comment: No, the [standard](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#subsection.2.6.1) states _"Objects with **generated** names are created by binding a generated name to the context"_.

Comment: Furthermore, each `glBind` call will report a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error if that name was not previously generated.

Comment: ... I think it is possible in a compatibility profile OpenGL context, but it it definitely not allowed in a core profile OpenGL context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In compatibility contexts, you're allow to just make up a (non-zero) number and pretend that's an object. In core contexts, you must generate them.

Comment: In the specifications of the [compatibility](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf) and [core](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) profile, section 2.6.1.1, about object creation, is identical. What you say is probably correct, but do you have a source?

Comment: It's the part where it says "*An `INVALID_OPERATION` error is generated if buffer is not zero or a name returned from a previous call to `GenBuffers`, or if such a name has since been deleted with `DeleteBuffers`.*", but for each object type. And where the compatibility specification *doesn't* have that.